# Is there a cap on Google Play Games levels?

Tags: google-play-games

I play a lot of mobile games. My Google Play level is currently 44. Is there a cap on the levels, or can I happily keep earning achievements and XP and levels forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highest level is 50 and has been that way since mid 2015. Might get increased if there's enough demand. Originally it was 20 then 25 and now 50.

Comment: I never really understood why they cap stuff like this. It's not like your Play account will be "too powerful" or something...

Comment: Yeah, it's silly. They do absolutely nothing for you, it's just a level!